# Android activity lifecycle callbacks

Tags: android, android-activity

Do activity lifecycle callbacks have to be implemented in pairs?

e.g.

- if you override `onCreate` you must also override `onDestroy` ?
- if you override `onStart` you must also override `onStop` ?
- if you override `onResume` you must also override `onPause` ?

i.e. would your app crash if you implement `onCreate` but omit to implement `onDestroy` say?

Is it just good practice to implement in pairs, or does it not matter at all (just implement what you need)?

Comment: why don't you try and tell....

Comment: well I have and my app is crashing on implementation of onStart and onResume when they only have log.D calls in them - I can't understand it hence me clutching at straws with the question above

Comment: Did you call `super.onStart()` and `super.onResume()`? See my edited answer below.

Comment: If your app crashes it always helps to post the logcat errors, so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Technically, but we're asking for the same thing -- LogCat is just the tool that displays the stack trace.

Comment: LogCat is Android's stack tracer. (In Eclipse, **Window** -> **Show View** -> **LogCat**, then highlight and Crtl+C).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only implement what you need. The others will automatically be called from the superclass (`Activity`). You should only override them if you need to add functionality at that point of the lifecycle. Typically, if you're handling something in `onPause()`, you're probably also going to handle the inverse operation in `onResume()`. That's definitely not always the case though.

EDIT: Going by your edit, without seeing the code, I'm going to guess you forgot the call to `super.onStart()` and `super.onResume()`. If not, post your implementations and stack trace for the crash.

Comment: good guess - that was my 1st mistake which I managed to spot earlier on, but I still have a crashing app that mysteriously works again when I comment out the onStart onResume methods - I'll have to learn how to get a stack trace then try and update my OP

Comment: If you get around to updating with the stack trace, @ reply to me so I get a notification, otherwise I won't see it.

Answer (score 2):

No. You do not *need* to override the lifecycle methods in pairs.

But if you need to explicitly release a variable that you created in one method, then it makes sense to release it in the matching method.

---

> Would your app crash if you implement onCreate but omit to implement onDestroy say?

A reoccurring question here on Stack Overflow deals with [closing SQLiteDatabases](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]+%E2%80%9Cclose%28%29+was+never+explicitly+called+on+database%E2%80%9D). Many programmers open their databases in `onCreate()` but forget to close them in `onDestory()`.